# Google Earth Engine cloud cover sorting and area of interest

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, cloud-cover

I see in a lot of examples that people are sorting a stack by cloud cover and then pick the first image.

Example:

```
image = image.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')
              .filterBounds(study_area)
              .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
              .first();
```

For me this is only useful if my entire area of interest falls into one image, which most often it does not (and which I often don't know before I get started).
Most of the time I get something like this:

[image]

If I understand right, the one image with least cloud cover is picked form the stack, so it makes sense that not my entire area is covered, as it is covered by multiple images.
So, what I don’t understand is why this is so commonly used.
Or am I totally missing something? Would it not be better to use median() or use a cloud masking function as we have the guarantee that the entire area is covered?

Comment: I agree that a more general procedure would be to mask clouds an do a median composite; however, I think that using the least cloudy image to perform analysis is commonly used due to its simplicity.

Comment: But that is only possible when the area is not covered by multiple images, i.e, you have to be lucky in the sense that your area “falls into” a single image. Or is there a way to get the least cloudy image**s** for a grid? E.g. your area is covered by 5 images and from the stack the algorithm pulls out the least cloudy image for each location where there should be an image (i.e. 5 images, instead of one).

Comment: Sure, you can use something like `aggregate_array().distinct()` to get the unique path rows or tile id in your roi and then `map` over that list to filter your collection by path row or tile id, and obtain the least cloudy image for each id. Then, you might want to use a reducer or mosaic to stitch them together.